# Refresh in memory cache of all google cloud function instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have an in-memory cache basically a map in a google cloud function instance.

I have created a trigger to update/refresh the cache it but the trigger is applied or processed by any one of the instance and that instance's cache is refreshed.

Other instances cache remain unrefreshed

Is there way where I can update the in memory cache of all google cloud function instances

Comment: You can't reach all the instance in the same time. You have to use a shared environment: database, Cloud Storage, Memory store, to, at least, get the info to invalidate the cache.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere how about adding a polling to a pubsub and when i get a message to pubsub all instances polling refresh themselves

Might work but looks like an over kill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reach all the instance in the same time. You have to use a shared environment: database, Cloud Storage, Memory store, to, at least, get the info to invalidate the cache.

You could imagine to create a PubSub connexion at the start up of all Cloud Functions. But it's not a good idea...

First of all, you are limited to 100 subscription per topic. Then, you will increase the cold start. Finally, you will have to cleanup the subscriptions when the instance is shut down (you can do that with Cloud Run or Cloud Functions gen2 by catching the sigkill)

You will also consume more resources on your Cloud Functions to keep the subscription pull open.

---

One recommended option/design is to check (at each request, or one a minute, or whatever) a place where you have the latest data update.

In your cloud function, you store that latest data update value. When you check the value, if it is the same, you continue.

If the value is greater in the "place", you have to invalidate your cache and reload it.

The "place" could be Firestore (it's fast and affordable). Cloud Storage is less safe and slower.

---

If you have a lot of traffic, and latency is important, Memorystore is a great cache solution also.